# In canonical transformation, is there any rules or methods for finding the transformation $(q,p)\to(Q,P)$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, phase-space

If we get two different Hamiltonian by using two methods of canonical formulation of theory and these two Hamiltonian are equivalent. How can I find the canonical transformation from which we can shift one Hamiltonian to another?

Comment: If you could transform both sets of coordinates to [Darboux coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem) (which are guaranteed to exist, at least locally), call those $\mathcal{Q}, \mathcal{P}$, then you could invert one of those transformations and go from $Q, P \rightarrow \mathcal{Q}, \mathcal{P} \rightarrow q, p$.

Comment: Hi RMAS 1.  For methods & rules, see e.g. chapter 9 in Goldstein. 2. The notation $(q,p)$ and $(Q,P)$ usually implicitly imply that they are both canonical/Darboux coordinates.

Comment: H_1=XP_Z+(\sqrt(Z)/36B) P_X^2+(3AX^2/2\sqrt Z). H_2=xp_z+(\sqrt z/36B)p_x^2-(x^2/z)p_x-(Az/6B)p_x+(A^2z^{3/2}/4B). A, B constants. How can find canonical transformation between two Hamiltonian, H_1 and H_2? Please help.